# summarise based on multiple columns with a lot of conditions

Tags: r, dplyr

**sample data**

```
df <- data.frame( id = 1:10,
                  group = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2),
                  p1 = c("A", NA, "A", "A", "B", NA, NA, NA, NA, "C"),
                  p2 = c("F", NA, "G", "G", "A", "H", NA, NA, NA, NA),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE )

#     id group   p1   p2
#  1   1     1    A    F
#  2   2     1 <NA> <NA>
#  3   3     1    A    G
#  4   4     1    A    G
#  5   5     1    B    A
#  6   6     2 <NA>    H
#  7   7     2 <NA> <NA>
#  8   8     2 <NA> <NA>
#  9   9     2 <NA> <NA>
# 10  10     2    C <NA>
```

I want to summarise `df` by group, so that I get columns of totals from

- unique id's
- unique id's where any of the p-columns value is not `NA`
- unique id's where any of the p-columns value is equal to "A"

**desired output**

```
data.frame( group = c(1,2),
            total = c(5,5),
            with_any_p = c(4,2),
            with_any_p_is_A = c(4,0),
            stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

#   group total with_any_p with_any_p_is_A
# 1     1     5          4               4
# 2     2     5          2               0
```

**code so far**

I know I can obtain the desired output using:

```
df %>% group_by( group ) %>% 
  summarise( total = n_distinct( id[] ),
             with_any_p = n_distinct( id[ !is.na(p1) | ! is.na(p2) ] ), 
             with_any_p_is_A = n_distinct( id[ p1 == "A" | p2 == "A" ], na.rm = TRUE ) )

# # A tibble: 2 x 4
#   group total with_any_p with_any_p_is_A
#   <dbl> <int>      <int>           <int>
# 1     1     5          4               4
# 2     2     5          2               0
```

**question**

but since my production data containt a lot of 'p-columns', I do not want to retype the above or-statements  for p1-p100

I can select the desired rows/subset with `filter_at`:

```
p.cols <- paste0( "p", 1:2 )
#for with_any_p
df %>% filter_at( vars( p.cols ), any_vars( !is.na(.) ) )
#for with_any_p_is_A
df %>% filter_at( vars( p.cols ), any_vars( . == "A" ) )
```

but I do know now how to get these kind of selections into summarise.

Can this be done in the same 'style' as the code I already have, so that I get the desired result in one go, without having to bind/join multiple results?

Comment: `by(df[, c("p1", "p2")], df$group, FUN = function(x){
    cbind(total = nrow(x), with_any_p = sum(as.logical(rowSums(is.na(x)))), with_any_p_is_A = sum(as.logical(rowSums(x == "A", na.rm = TRUE))))
    })`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution for an arbitrary number of `"p"` columns using an initial wide-to-long conversion

```
df %>%
    gather(key, val, -id, -group) %>%
    group_by(group) %>%
    summarise(
        total = n_distinct(id),
        with_any_p = n_distinct(id[!is.na(val)]),
        with_any_p_is_A = n_distinct(id[val == "A"], na.rm = T))
## A tibble: 2 x 4
#  group total with_any_p with_any_p_is_A
#  <dbl> <int>      <int>           <int>
#1     1     5          4               4
#2     2     5          2               0
```

A comment: I assume that all columns except `id` and `group` are `"p"` columns. If this is not the case you may have to change the `gather` statement to reflect your more general column structure.

Comment: Smart! I hadn't thought about switching to long(er) format.  What works better (for me) is `df %>% gather(key, val, p.cols ) %>% ...` so that I do not have to deselect multiple columns...